# Bitmap Image is not sharpen

Tags: java, android, flutter, png, android-bitmap

I'm including a launch image for my android application in Flutter. However this image is either blurry or too big. When I view the image on my hard drive it is sharp. How can I keep the image sharp?

/res/drawable/launch_background.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/background" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_transparent_256" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

/res/values/styles.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

current result: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQq6P.png)

actual image: [logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbUew.png)

Comment: Can you post the code where you use this layer-list drawable?

Comment: @IanMedeiros I edited my question. Basically the layer-list is loaded in the styles.xml

Comment: 256x256 is pretty small as some splash screens are now 2560x1600.  'Center' should place it in the center and not resize it, but even then, on some devices, it would be too tiny, and unacceptable.  You need different versions of that graphic at different sizes, and you need to put them in drawable folders specific to each resolution... HDMI etc.

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael Dougan pointed out, the image size was too small and instead of saving one version of the launch image in `/res/drawable/`, it is better so save the image in different sizes (e.g. `/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi`)